# How to concat all the entries of one column [SQL]

Tags: sql, string-aggregation

As the title states, with the following SQL query:

```
SELECT "Name"
FROM "ExampleTable"
```

I get the following result:

```
Name
----------------
ExampleName1
ExampleName2
ExampleName3
```

**Question:** how to modify the query so that all the names are to be displayed in a row, so that they can be later used an array.

**What I tried:** `FOR XML`, `STUFF` - doesn't work

**Expected result:**

```
Name: ExampleName1, ExampleName2, ExampleName3.
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server you can try this:

```
Select SUBSTRING( 
( 
     SELECT ',' + Name AS 'data()'
         FROM TableName FOR XML PATH('') 
), 2 , 1000) As Names
```

Check this on Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6ab0b3/6

Or may be an easy way using `COALESCE` that combines the multiple rows in single row separated by Comma separated values based on parameters passed:

```
Declare @val Varchar(MAX); 
Select @val = COALESCE(@val + ', ' + Name, Name) 
        From TableName Select @val;

select @val; // this will show all your data
```

Check this on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/36112/2

Also, I am giving the screenshots for you to easily understand the steps if something goes wrong with the above screenshots.

**Please note:** In the above process, neither I have taken any PRIMARY KEY nor I am setting its auto-increment, but in the upcoming explanation I have used PRIMARY KEY as I have written everything in SSMS (Sql Server Management Studio)

Here is the schema for sample `tblStudent` table with PRIMARY KEY and auto increment set as you can see below:

[image]

Next enter some dummy values in it

[image]

finally write our query.

[image]

Comment: Hey, both ways, didn't work,  `FOR XML - incorrect syntax new 'data()'  `, even if `'data()'` is deleted, it doesn't work and `COALESCE - statement is only allowed inside a procedure and function block `. Still thank you for you answer!

Comment: @user13047397 I have added the fiddle link for you to check. Write your query exactly as mentioned in it.

Comment: @user13047397 check my updates. I have added screenshots for you to better understand the process I followed. Hope this helps getting perfect result you want.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer and great contribution! @noobprogrammer, i am going to try it out upcoming monday!

Comment: It's not quite allowed to change column properties, thus it doesn't really work but still Thank you! Your Answer is quality and might help someone, so I am going to accept your answer!

Comment: @user13047397 Thanks for accepting the answer :) Bdw what column property are you looking to change?